# Why can't std::iterator_traits find value_type?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

Why can't I compile next code?

```
#include <iterator>

struct test_iterator {
    using value_type = int;
};

int main()
{
    std::iterator_traits<test_iterator>::value_type a  = 0;
    return a;
}
```

It seems that all three major compilers(msvc/gcc/clang) cannot compile this code.

As far as I know, `std::iterator_traits` works like:

```
template <class T>
struct iterator_traits {
    using value_type = typename T::value_type;
    ... // other memebers
};
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: From [iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) since C++17: *"If Iterator does not have the five member types difference_type, value_type, pointer, reference, and iterator_category, then this template has no members by any of those names (std::iterator_traits is SFINAE-friendly)"*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits), since C++17:

> "If Iterator does not have the five member types difference_type, value_type, pointer, reference, and iterator_category, then this template has no members by any of those names (`std::iterator_traits` is SFINAE-friendly)"

Providing the missing types fixes the error: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6ab018aa92e44d5)

C++20 adds new ways to fill members if iterator satisfies some concepts.